# Picture not visible

Tags: css, mobile

I am trying to optimize my website for mobile view. Everything is working fine and responsive but the logo becomes invisible when accessed through mobile but visible through pc.

I tried with .png, .gif format but result is same. also jpg gave the same output.This is mobile screenshot.

[image]

This is the desktop screenshot:[image]

```
<div >
<h1 ><img src="images/icon.png" width="15%" height="auto"/>
</h1>
</div>
```

changed the code to:

```
<div style="margin:1em;">
<img class="logo" src="images/icon.png" /> 
</div>
```

css:
.logo{display:block;width:15%;height:auto"}

Still not visible. Can it be a browser issue? I am using WP8.

Comment: and would u mind showing html and css you have done for this?

Comment: we are going to need your CSS and HTML to help you.

Comment: You really need to link to the real thing. The cause could be anything, including @media rules.

Comment: http://opensourceeducation.in/ , from the SS above

Comment: Add CSS also...or give link to online site..if it is

Comment: Logo is visible on my end...!

Comment: (side note: line6 is missing a closing `>` )

Comment: Showing on my Android device as well..

Comment: remove img from h1 markup and add style display:block;
<img class="logo" src="images/icon.png" />
.logo{
width:15%;
height:auto;
display:block;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mcmac: Things working :)

that change solved the issue.
final code:

```
<div style="margin:1em;">
<img class="logo" src="images/icon.png" /> 
</div>
```

css: 
    .logo{display:block;width:15%;height:auto"}